# AWS SAM - 'Encountered unsupported property CodeUri' error when deploying packaged template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

After migrating a CloudFormation template to AWS SAM approach, when deploying template created with `aws cloudformation package`, in CloudFormation I get error

> Encountered unsupported property CodeUri

on all Lambda functions that are included in the template.

After investigation, it's clear that CodeUri property is not removed from the packaged template and [AWS::Lambda::Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html) type doesn't support **CodeUri** property, although proper resources are uploaded to S3 as part of the package process (so package as such works).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for AWS SAM not removing **CodeUri** is incorrect resource type - it should be `AWS::Serverless::Function` and not `AWS::Lambda::Function`.

After this change, **CodeUri** is removed from the packaged template.

Comment: Which in turn requires `Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'` as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-cli-package.html

Answer (score 0):

You just should set the path to your function file in a proper format with `Code`, `S3Bucket` and `S3Key` keys:

```
Function:
  Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
  Properties
    //other properties
    Code:
      S3Bucket: bucketName
      S3Key: myFunction.jar
```

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-code

In my case, I was creating a stack with existing resources (import resources), and there `AWS::Serverless::Function` type with its **CodeUri** isn't supported.